# Several ACLs on same parseobject

Tags: android, parse-platform

Say I have a ParseObject and I want to set several ParceAcl object on the same parse object. Each ACL object associated with different user. For example say I have 2 ParseUsers:

```
ParseUser user1 = ...
....
....
ParseUser user2 = ....
....
ParseACL permissions1  = new ParceACL();
permission1.setReadAccess(user1,false);
permission1.setWriteAccess(user1,true);

ParseACL permissions2  = new ParceACL();
permission2.setReadAccess(user2,true);
permission1.setWriteAccess(user2,false);
```

How do I set the 2 permissions on the same ParseGame object? After all the parsegameobject has method 
named setACL that takes onlt one ParceACL object...

Thank u in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create group acls as shown in [the docs](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#users-acls).

```
ParseACL groupACL = new ParseACL();

groupACL.setReadAccess(user1, false);
groupACL.setWriteAccess(user1, true);  

groupACL.setReadAccess(user2, true);
groupACL.setWriteAccess(user2, false);  

gameObject.setACL(groupACL);
gameObject.saveInBackground();
```